# How to add recurring entry Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, recurring

I would like to add a recurring event with C#. I found on the Web that the following should work. When I run the method to insert the entry, It fails on the
    EventEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(calendarUri, entry); statement !

I get this error :
"Execution of request failed: 
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user@gmail.com/private/full?gsessionid=6eGsOTuhQ-YUVWp2BV_25g"

When I remove the recurrence code, everything works fine ! I noticed that this piece of code is pretty old ! How can I simply add a recurring event on Google Calendar with the .NET library ?

```
EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();
entry.Title.Text = "Hello World !";

// Recurring event:   

String recurData =
"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20131010;BYDAY=SU\r\n";

Recurrence recurrence = new Recurrence();
recurrence.Value = recurData;
entry.Recurrence = recurrence;

string htmlDescription = "Woww, really ?";

if (htmlDescription != null && htmlDescription.Length > 0)
{
    entry.Content.Type = "html";
    entry.Content.Content = htmlDescription;
}


Where eventLocation = new Where();
eventLocation.ValueString = "Somewhere";
entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);


DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

When eventTime = new When();
eventTime.StartTime = start;

DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
eventTime.EndTime = endTime;


entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

eventTime.AllDay = true;
EventEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(calendarUri, entry);
```

Comment: "When I try it I get an error." is absolutely meaningless to everyone except you unless you tell us what "an error" means. Is it a compiler error? A runtime error? Where is the error happening? Please edit your question and explain the error you're getting, along with the **exact** error message you're seeing. Expecting us to read through your code trying to figure it out is going to make getting you help much slower.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right ! I edited with the exact error, which it still, to me, meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from Google (click the .NET example if it doens't come up as a default):[Create Recurring Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents)

Hopefully this will give you some ideas if not out-right answer your question.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that is good ! I read it before. The only problem is that I need to register my applicatiosn through the Google API console. I was trying to figure out another simpler way to do it. I guess I will have to register it !

Answer (score 1):

Your recurrence string telling it when to end requires a full time entry.  You simply said UNTIL=20131010.  The question is 20131010 where? We can assume you want midnight, but then... midnight where?

```
String recurData =
"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20131010T000000-05:00;BYDAY=SU\r\n";
```

The above change should make your event recur until Midnight US Eastern time on 2013-10-10.